# Need help creating a plugin system for the game engine

Tags: rust, mutex, game-engine, refcell

[Github repository](https://github.com/klementievdmitry/nazh-engine)

## A little about how the plugin system should roughly work.

The Plugin trait implements the `build()` method, which is called when the plugin is loaded. The `build()` method takes `App` struct, where `App` is the application structure.

**Now my code looks cumbersome. So the question is, are there any other options?**

```rust
pub trait Component {
    fn start(&mut self);
    fn update(&mut self);
}

pub struct App {
    runners: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut App)>>,
    components: Vec<Box<dyn Component>>,
}
```

### `&mut App`

Initially, the `build()` method took `&mut App`, but this did not allow me to do the following:

```rust
impl Plugin for WinitWSIPlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: &mut App) {
        app.set_runner(move || {
            // Error here
            app.open_window(...);
        });
    }
}
```

As I understood the compiler did not allow me to do this, because I passed a reference to the `App` structure, which may soon be irrelevant.

### Rc<RefCell>

In the following implementation, I passed `Rc<RefCell<App>>`, but calling `borrow_mut()` to call `open_window(...)` had a panic, even though I had not manually called `borrow_mut()` before.

```rust
impl Plugin for WinitWSIPlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: Rc<RefCell<App>>) {
        app.clone().borrow().set_runner(move || {
            let AppSystem::Windowed { info } = app.borrow().system();
            let mut winit_windows = WinitWindows::default();
            let event_loop = winit::event_loop::EventLoop::new();

            /*===== Panic this =====*/
            app.borrow_mut().open_window(winit_windows.create_window(
                &event_loop,
                app.borrow().id(),
                &info,
            ));
        });
    }
}
```

### The last revision I stopped at.

Using `Mutex` in those fields of the App structure that will be used in the plugins. That way, I won't have to call `borrow_mut()` even if I need to change the value. It will be enough to call `borrow()`

```rust
impl Plugin for WinitWSIPlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: Rc<RefCell<App>>) {
        app.clone().borrow().set_runner(move || {
            let AppSystem::Windowed { info } = app.borrow().system();
            let mut winit_windows = WinitWindows::default();
            let event_loop = winit::event_loop::EventLoop::new();
            app.borrow().open_window(winit_windows.create_window(
                &event_loop,
                app.borrow().id(),
                &info,
            ));

            for component in app.borrow().components().borrow_mut().iter_mut() {
                component.init(app.clone());
            }

            let app = app.clone();
            event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
                control_flow.set_wait();

                for component in app.borrow().components().borrow_mut().iter_mut() {
                    component.update(app.clone());
                }

                match event {
                    winit::event::Event::WindowEvent {
                        window_id: _,
                        event,
                    } => match event {
                        winit::event::WindowEvent::CloseRequested => control_flow.set_exit(),
                        _ => (),
                    },
                    _ => (),
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `trait Component` is inconsistent with how you use it (is it `start` or `init`, does it take a reference to `App` or just `&self`). Maybe give [mre] a read and provide one.

Comment: I solved this problem. Previously, I had passed a reference to `App` when launching the application, although I could have also passed ownership to `App` (i.e. `Box<dyn Fn(App)>` instead of `Box<dyn Fn(&mut App)>`), because once launched the application is not meant to be used. But thanks a lot, now I have an idea how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You could get around having to share `App` (which I'm not sure will work anyways) by just passing it into the closure as a parameter:

```rust
struct App {
    runners: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut App)>>,
}
impl App {
    fn set_runner(&mut self, f: impl Fn(&mut App) + 'static) {
        self.runners.push(Box::new(f));
    }
    fn run(&mut self) {
        // take the runners out of self to avoid borrow & mutable borrow at the same time
        let runners = std::mem::take(&mut self.runners);
        for runner in runners.iter() {
            // pass self into the runner so it can change app state and create windows etc
            runner(self);
        }
        // put the runners back.
        self.runners = runners;
    }
    fn open_window(&mut self) {}
}

trait Plugin {
    fn build(&self, app: &mut App);
}
struct WinitWSIPlugin;
impl Plugin for WinitWSIPlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: &mut App) {
        // the closure now takes a `&mut App` as parameter
        // the argument type is optional and just shown for demonstration here
        app.set_runner(move |app: &mut App| {
            app.open_window();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have already used this implementation. But I can't pass this link to other closures. That is, I can't pass the application structure to `winit::event_loop`

Comment: I think in this case i could wrap `dyn Component` in `Rc<RefCell<dyn Component>>`, and pass it to another closure. That doesn't sound like a bad solution to me. At least better than my last one.

Comment: You're not making a lot of sense to me. `winit::event_loop` is a module, you can't pass structs to modules. And there is no `trait Component` anywhere in your code or mine.

Comment: `winit::event_loop` is a module that has a structure `EventLoop<>`. This structure has a `run()` method that takes a closure as an argument. I added `trait Component` and `App` to the question